# PostgreSQL query to join tble1 with multiple table based on common id to validate features and attribute

Tags: postgis

I have 3 shapefiles imported into PostgreSQL with PostGIS to do query find out if any mismatch. So now I want left join the `Table1` on to `Table2` and `Table3` on id retrieve two results

```
1.) Geomtery - 
`Table2.geom` based on recent date if 2 or more id matches on `table2` . 
`Table3.geom` if 1 id matches from Table2 and 1 id from Table3.

2.) Attribute - 
`Itmtype` and other Attribute based on Older Date. however in both case I would concatenate Number of `sry_unique` and `SurveyCounts` as Number of item found. and
```

I tried below code but it still needed me code more so please suggest me how do I improve on it to achieve what I needed as below.

```
SELECT t1.id,
          count(t2.sry_unique),
          count(DISTINCT(t3.sry_unique)) ,

          string_agg(t2.sry_unique,', ' ORDER BY t2.date) AS uniqueref_att,

          string_agg(DISTINCT t3.sry_unique,', ') AS lidar_att,
          t1.geom
   FROM table t1
   LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
   LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
   GROUP BY t1.id
```

**Output table should look smilar to this.**

```
+----+--------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+
| id | surveycounts | Itmtype  | sry_unique | tble2.id | tbl2.Itmtype | tble2.olderITM |  tble2.sry_unique   | tble2._RecentSryUnique | tble2.Olderecent_SryUnique | tbl2.Date  | tble3.id | tble3.Date | tble3.sry_uniqe |  Geom_match   | Attribute |
+----+--------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+
|  1 |            1 | MG       | XXX1       |        1 | MG           | MG             | XXX1                | XXX1                   | XXX1                       | RecentDate |        1 | olderDate  | XXXXXTY1        | tble3geomtery |           |
|  2 |            2 | SG       | XXX2       |        2 | SX,SG        | SG             | XXX2, XX2_X         | XXX2                   | XXX2_X                     | RecentDate |        2 | olderDate  | XXXXXTY1        | tble2geomtery |           |
|  3 |            3 | MN       | XXX3       |        2 | SG,MN,MX,MYY | MN             | XXX3,XXX3_X,XXX3_XX | XXX3                   | XXX3_XX                    | RecentDate |        3 | olderDate  | XXXXXTY3        | tble2geomtery |           |
+----+--------------+----------+------------+----------+--------------+----------------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+------------+----------+------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+
```

**Table1 - Main Data**

```
+----+--------------+----------+------------+
| id | surveycounts | Itmtype  | sry_unique |
+----+--------------+----------+------------+
|  1 |            1 | MG       | XXX1       |
|  2 |            2 | SG       | XXX2       |
|  3 |            3 | MN       | XXX3       |
+----+--------------+----------+------------+
```

**Table2 - Multiple Survey Data**

```
+----+--+---------+------------+------------+--+
| id |  | Itmtype | sry_unique |    Date    |  |
+----+--+---------+------------+------------+--+
|  1 |  | MG      | XXX1       | 2015-11-04 |  |
|  2 |  | GN      | XXX2       | 2011-12-03 |  |
|  2 |  | SG      | XXX2_X     | 2010-06-03 |  |
|  3 |  | MN1     | XXX3       | 2009-05-03 |  |
|  3 |  | MXx     | XXX3_X     | 2009-01-02 |  |
|  3 |  | MX      | XXX3_XX    | 2008-02-16 |  |
+----+--+---------+------------+------------+--+
```

**Table3 - LidarData**

```
+----------+--------------+
| lidar_id | lidar_unique |
+----------+--------------+
|        1 | XXXXXTY1     |
|        2 | XXXXXTY1     |
|        3 | XXXXXTY3     |
+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: If you want to find *missing* matches, you need to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.